# Googlemap javascript v3+php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have made connection with database at top and fetched the records in associative array

```
<? php include_once('dbconnect.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM maps";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arr[] = $row;
}
?>
```

I have a script at the bottom but about the `</body>` tag which is given below:

```
  <script>
  function initialize(){
  var map;
   var locations = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
  var strfy=JSON.stringify(locations);

   var location=JSON.parse(locations);

   var mapoption={
    zoom: 10,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
   };
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapoption);

   var infowindow= new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   var marker,i;
   for(i=0;i<location.length;i++){

     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.query.lat,location.query.longits),
      map: map
      });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(location.name);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
     })(marker, i));
     }

     }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I have the body part at middle

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:380px;"></div>
```

The record has been successfully fetched in associative array but I'm facing a problem. When I run the localhost, it doesn't show me googlemap but errors

[image]

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are explicitly setting protocol when adding google maps api. 
For localhost it should start with http:// or https://. It will tell browser to load library from web and not from filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a var location is a global variable - window.location, so when you trying to assign a value, browser does redirect, just rename it, or do something like that

(function(){ 
 YOUR_CODE_HERE
})();

for encapsulation

You need somethink like this:

```
function initialize() {
    var map;
    var locations = <? php echo json_encode($arr); ?> ;// $arr must be not an associative array

    //2 next strings doesn't metter
    //var strfy = JSON.stringify(locations);
    //var location = JSON.parse(strfy);

    alert(locations);
    var mapoption = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapoption);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker;
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].longits),
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i].name);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: ok..i did what you said but it show problem like  too much recursion
 too much recursion

...rCase()+"_changed"};var tb=function(a){a.gm_accessors_||(a.gm_accessors_={});ret...

Comment: first problem was a url path like [object Object][object Object]

Comment: sorry the actual problem came isReferenceError: json is not defined
 

var location=json.parse(locations);

Comment: isReferenceError: json is not defined var location=json.parse(locations);

Comment: your code has 2 problems: you trying to parse JSON form object as string(first error), and then you always uses the location variable in for statement, just use my code above(without alert calling), it's can be used from head or body tags, but be careful with locations variable, before using see it via console.log(), it's must to be thomething like that [{lat: 33, longits: 151, name: 'foo'}, ... ]

Comment: why the array should not be associative array?and why not to use json_encode here please guide me here

Comment: if im trying to parse JSON from object, isn't there any way to convert object ...

Comment: it's already JSON object. There is no associative arrays in javascript, associative arrays from php after json_encode becomes an Objects(keys maight be a string or may be in another order), in that case you should use `for` `in`(or `each` function from js frameworks) statement instead of `for` or `forEach`